# Nginx Reverse Proxy URIs

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two EC2 instances running nginx web server. Box 1 is the 'main website' and box 2 is an API search service.

I have set up box 1 so that the search page proxies box 2 and whilst this works fine I am struggling to manage the results in terms of their URIs.

For example an individual will search on box 1, box 2 presents the results accordingly (whilst maintaining box 1 url) however when any of the results are clicked on then the site redirects to box 2.

The expected/anticipated result is that I can proxy the result page from box 2 also. I have copied the basic config below and hoping for some direction.

I was hoping that there maybe a 'location ''catch all''' that I could set to say anything past /location/search/results would all be proxied however this does not seem to be the case.

```
        location /search/ {
        proxy_pass https://api.website.co.uk/search/location/;

        proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
        proxy_http_version            1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }
```

The URLs for the search results themselves typically look like the below;

```
https://beta.website.co.uk/search/location/property/12345/listing
```

Box 1 is `beta.website.co.uk`
Box 2 is `api.website.co.uk`